# Django directing users after login

Tags: python, django

I've got problems login people with my django app, and I don't think I quite understand how login currently works. Here's my user class, that extends Django's user with some extra fields. The extra fields indicate the type of the user, which I'll just call A, B and C.

```
class MyUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    isA = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    isB = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    isC = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I've got a login view that should redirect the users as per their type:

```
def myLogin(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    myuser = MyUser.objects.get(user=user)

    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            if myuser.isA:
                return redirect('/aView/')
             elif myuser.isB:
                return redirect('/bView/')
            elif myuser.isC:
                return redirect('/cView/')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('disabled account')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Invalid login')
```

and my template is the default login template from the django docs:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% if form.errors %}
<p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}

{% if next %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
     <p>Your account doesn't have access to this page. To proceed,
    please login with an account that has access.</p>
    {% else %}
    <p>Please login to see this page.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}

<form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="login" />
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Currently I get an error sayin:

```
DoesNotExist at /login/
MyUser matching query does not exist.
```

I'm wondering also, that shouldn't I link my "login.html" file to myLogin view? Any help is much appriciated!

Comment: Looks like the `MyUser` object for the corresponding user does not exist yet (it does **not** magically get created, even with `OneToOneField`). You might want to use `myuser, created = MyUser.objects.get_or_create(user=user)`  or similar.

Answer (score 0):

The `get` `QuerySet` method raises an `DoesNotExist` exception if there is no matching entry. The line `myuser = MyUser.objects.get(user=user)` needs changing.

#### try/except

```
try:
    myuser = MyUser.objects.get(user=user)
except MyUser.DoesNotExist:
    myuser = None
```

#### check with exists (extra query)

```
 myuser_qs = MyUser.objects.filter(user=user)
 myuser = myuser_qs.get() if myuser_qs.exists() else None
```

this will still warn if there are `MyUser.MultipleObjectsReturned`

#### using first/last QuerySet methods

```
myuser = MyUser.objects.filter(user=user).first()
```

this will return `None` if not matching entry is there, but the downside is that if you have multiple entries in the database, there won't be an error raised

---

Reading [relevant Django source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.10.x/django/db/models/query.py#L550) might be helpful

Comment: I think shortcut function `myuser = get_object_or_404(MyUser, pk=user)` is slightly better solution